# How to pass in the correct variables when using tensorflow.sess.run()?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, placeholder

I'm constructing several complex neural networks now using tensorflow. They share some variables and come neural network's output is another neural network's input. Sometimes I just get confused of which variables I should pass in to tf.sess.run()? Cause the structure is not very easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have two models (model1 and model2) and model1 output is input for model2 then model2 will come in sess.run().
In sess.run() that model will come which is giving you last prediction.